# Song being played in background and user again clicks app icon

Tags: android

My app is a music player app and using bound service in my app, everything working fine except if i open the app play a song from list of searched result and press the home button or back button, song is being played in background(through bound service) and then again I launch the app by clicking app icon, now seekbar is moving but pause button is changed into play button and there is not list of searched result(every thing is on initial stage except seekbar).

How can i open the app on clicking app icon from situation where i left the app? Thanks for your time and help

Comment: You have to restore play/pause button state each time you're binding to the service. To restore list of songs you have to store it also inside service (but they'll be lost if service is destroyed) or in persistent storage. To restore list of songs on screen rotation for example you can use onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState methods. More detailed answer seems to be impossible without seeing your code.

Comment: is it not possible to open my app on clicking launcher icon just like it opens from recent tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in my manifest file in launcher activity

```
<activity
                android:name=""
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
```

and it started behaving exactly like what i want